# Does the order of these four names govern the steps in attaining moksha?

Tags: moksha, sadhana, lalita-sahasranama, inner-meaning

Consider the [following four names](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Lalitha_Sahasranamam) from Lalitha Sahastranaama

> **Loka theetha**  She who is beyond the world
>
> **Guna theetha**  She who is beyond properties
>
> **Sarvatheetha**  She who is beyond everything
>
> **Samathmika**    She who is peace

It is well mentioned in scriptures that para brahman is beyond lokas, gunas, and everything and is in the form of peace only (Shaantaakaaram).

But I want to know the significance of the order of names and the inner meaning behind this order of four names.

```
beyond lokas (1) -> beyond gunas (2) -> beyond everything (3) -> sama (4)
```

Are these the **order of realizations** that a sadhaka needs to undergo or perceive para brahman in order to reach the ultimate moksha state i.e, realizing para brahman as Samathmika?

Does any scripture explicitly mention this order of realizations? I mean does a sadhaka needs to go beyond lokas *first* and then gunas and then everything and finally reach the moksha state?

Comment: I think it rather must b, 1st gunatita ie transcend good bad, trigunas, then a person becomes sarvatita i.e. beyond everything (all prapanch), then the person becomes Lokateeta (14 lokas signigying steps to realization as said by Baskararay) & finally Samatmika ie ultimate happiness. Maybe Im wrong, but first person must win dualities which arise of gunas, then only d person transcends everything, finally finding oneness wid Brahman, & b in esctacy. This is my personal tght, no 1 can understnd LS completely if u had this tght, it must be true. As, evry tght comes by her will.Thus, its frm her.